# Как выполнить процесс в нескольких потоках

Tags: c#, tpl

Хочу параллельно выполнить get-запросы, однако нет синхронизация взятия значения из массива. Если я сделаю `lock` при взятии значения из `getmyseller`, то смысл многопоточности теряет смысл. Как быть?

```
 Parallel.For(0, getmyseller.offers.Count(), i => {
      int j = i += 100;
      var hundred = string.Join(",", getmyseller.offers.Skip(j).Take(100).Select(x => x.i_classid + "_" + x.i_instanceid).ToList());

      using(WebClient wcc = new WebClient()) {
       var values = new NameValueCollection {
        {
         "list",
         hundred
        }
       };

       if (minus1 == true) {

        json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wcc.UploadValues("https://xxx1?key=" + apiKey, "POST", values));
        massinfo1.AddRange(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize < MassInfo1 > (json).results);

       } else {

        json = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wcc.UploadValues("https://xxx2?key=" + apiKey, "POST", values));
        massinfo2.AddRange(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize < MassInfo2 > (json).results);

       }
      }
     });
```

Comment: Так берите из массива ДО Parallel.For.

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с пространством имен System.Collections.Concurrent - типы из этого пространства имен оптимизированы для работы из нескольких потоков

Comment: спасибо, но хотелось бы больше подробностей

Comment: Если `getmyseller.offers` это массив, который постоянно обновляется - почему нельзя сделать **producer/consumer** сценарий и работать с `BlockingCollection` потокобезопасно?